# undefiend parameter in function while passing it through props react js

Tags: reactjs

**i am passing a function called updatenote from parent file to child file through props but when i am calling it , i am getting a error in child class currentnote parameter of updateNote is not defined**
[parent file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qaCOB.png)[child file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4WEV.png)

Comment: You need to provide more information, i.e., how you're passing the function, what the name of the prop is, etc.

Comment: i am passing function through props you can see it in parentfile line no 76  and it has a same name as the function updateNote

Comment: Bro you gotta separate the links with a space, that looks like a single link. Also add a screenshot of the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so the issue is that you don't have a variable named `currentnote` anywhere in the `Noteitem` file. You need to have a variable named `currentnote` already defined to pass it through the function.

The function is throwing an undefined error because it cannot find the variable being passed to it.

Answer (score 0):

**In your child component:**

```
const NoteItem = (props) => {
  const { buttonOnClickHandler } = props;

  return <button onClick={buttonOnClickHandler}>Click me</button>;
};
```

**In your parent component:**

```
<NoteItem buttonOnClickHandler={updateNote} />
```